# IndexError: list index out of range when assigning values to tuples from a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, append

I am trying to create two sets of tuples to use as coordinates for the colour of the squares of a chessboard but I can't seem to get rid of the error: "IndexError: list index out of range".

Do you have an idea as to why it returns this error?

```
alpha = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g"]

chessSquareBlack = []
chessSquareWhite = []

for i in range(8):
    for j in range(8):

        if ((i+1) % 2 == 0 and (j+1) % 2 != 0) or (i+1) % 2 != 0 and (j+1) % 2 == 0:
            chessSquareBlack.append(((alpha[i]),(j+1)))

        elif ((i+1) % 2 != 0 and (j+1) % 2 == 0) or (i+1) % 2 == 0 and (j+1) % 2 != 0:
            chessSquareWhite.append(((alpha[i]), (j+1)))
```

Comment: Please show the stack trace as well (what particular line of code the error points to).

Comment: use 7 in range `for i in range(7):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list `alpha` has a length of 7, but you are iterating up to 7. Since python starts indexing at 0, you get an `IndexError`.

Just change `range(8)` to `range(7)` and you are good.

However it should be said that in your second if statement for the white squares something is wrong with your conditions, as it is never actually opened as the condition is always `false`.

Comment: Well, now I feel dumb.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
alpha = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g"]

chessSquareBlack = []
chessSquareWhite = []
```

Instead of 7 or 8, you can check the length of the list "alpha" and use it in the for loop as below. This would be generic and hence you will not have to hardcode it everytime:

**range(len(alpha))**

```
for i in range(len(alpha)):
    for j in range(len(alpha)):
    #enter code here
```

Comment: I will definitely be using this method in the future, fewer chances of getting it wrong!